# AngularJS : function triggers twice on ng-change while selecting any option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

Actually I am new to angularjs and I am facing problem which confuses me alot.
I have written angularjs controller, it populates data in dropdown menu and selection of each option it should show particular location on map. To trigger event I have used ng-change.

My HTML view looks like,

```
<select name="DeviceList" ng-model="deviceList" ng-change="filterMarkers()">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
                                        <option ng-repeat="device in data" value="{{device.id}}">{{device.name}}</option>
                                </select>
```

JSON object looks like,

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "MacVend1001",
"latitude": "12.9383145",
"longitude": "77.57274628",
"status": "ON",
"failureMessage": null,
"healthIndex": [{
    "Parameter": "Voltage",
    "value": "29",
    "y-axis": [244, 124, 226, 372, 180, 290, 135, 350, 175, 145],
    "x-axis": ["2016-01-01 13:49:32", "2016-01-02 13:48:43", "2016-01-03 13:48:43", "2016-01-04 13:48:43", "2016-01-05 13:49:32", "2016-01-06 13:48:43", "2016-01-07 13:48:43", "2016-01-08 13:48:43", "2016-01-09 13:48:43", "2016-01-10 13:48:43"],
    "chart-type": "Trend"
}, {
    "Parameter": "Internal Temprature",
    "value": "30",
    "y-axis": [44, 24, 26, 72, 80, 90, 35, 50, 75, 45],
    "x-axis": ["2016-01-01 13:49:32", "2016-01-02 13:48:43", "2016-01-03 13:48:43", "2016-01-04 13:48:43", "2016-01-05 13:49:32", "2016-01-06 13:48:43", "2016-01-07 13:48:43", "2016-01-08 13:48:43", "2016-01-09 13:48:43", "2016-01-10 13:48:43"],
    "chart-type": "Trend"
}, {
    "Parameter": "External Temprature",
    "value": "45",
    "y-axis": [144, 224, 126, 372, 180, 2940, 1355, 250, 175, 345],
    "x-axis": ["2016-01-01 13:49:32", "2016-01-02 13:48:43", "2016-01-03 13:48:43", "2016-01-04 13:48:43", "2016-01-05 13:49:32", "2016-01-06 13:48:43", "2016-01-07 13:48:43", "2016-01-08 13:48:43", "2016-01-09 13:48:43", "2016-01-10 13:48:43"],
    "chart-type": "Trend"
}]
```

}]

and finally Controller is here,

```
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('NewMapCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.data=[];
    $http({method:'GET',url: 'https://korbsbvm130.apac.bosch.com:8244/intelrfc/1.0/devicelist'}).success(function(API_RESPONSE){
        $scope.data=API_RESPONSE;
        $scope.devicelist=0;
    });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.city,
            Name:info.name
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.city + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.name + '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.Name +'<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
        $scope.markers.push(marker);
    }

  for (i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        createMarker($scope.data[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

    $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
        $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      $scope.markers.length = 0;
    }



    $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
       //1.select filtered cities
       var devicesData;
       var deviceName = $scope.deviceList;
       if(deviceName == '0') {
          devicesData = $scope.data;
       }
       else {
          devicesData = $scope.data.filter(function(c){
              alert("C.id="+c.id)
            if(c.id == deviceName)
               return c; 
          });
       }  
       //2.update markers on map
       $scope.clearMarkers();
       for (i = 0; i < devicesData.length; i++) {
        createMarker(devicesData[i]);
       }
    }

});
```

Now the problem is whenever I click on any option from populated dropdown it calls filtermarkers() function twice, but usually it should not. Kindly share your idea to how to get rid of it.

It also shows me two empty options in populated dropdown list.

[image: empty options]

Answer (score 0):

You have probably just not configured the select directive properly.. I don't remember seeing a value attribute in the select directive.. Here is a plunker showing simple use, configured to call a function when the selection changes.

https://plnkr.co/edit/zOZ9Tqv4r5rYPXTNyICx?p=preview

The markup:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="someFunction()">
        <option ng-repeat="device in someArray">{{device.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i think it's more correct (angularJS-wise!) to use `ng-value="device.id"` instead of `value="{{device.id}}"`. also you can simply pass $index as that value (like `ng-value="$index"`) and then access the selected data inside the `$scope.filterMarkers` function like this: `devicesData = $scope.data[$scope.deviceList]` instead of using a filter...

but aside from that, i think problem might be coming from the fact that you are defining the `$scope.devicelist` after the response comes from the server. and before that happens, angular creates another variable while rendering the page and seeing `ng-model="deviceList"` so maybe that's causing the problem.

this also might happen because of defining the controller for your page more than one time. like defining it inside your html with `ng-controller="something"` and at the same time assigning it to the app in your JS files... that causes for the controller function to run twice from start... (you can test this by putting a console.log("someText") in your controller and see if it gets logged more than one time)

anyway, probably the best way to check for this (considering i can't see and run all your code), is to simply trace your code with tools like chrome's devtools and see what happens with it and who is calling the function again...

hope it's been of any help!